# Cassandra difference between ANY and ONE consistency levels

Tags: cassandra, replication, consistency

Assumptions: RF = 3

In some video on the Internet about Consistency level speaker says that CL = ONE is better then CL = ANY because when we use CL = ANY coordinator will be happy to store only hint(and data)(we are assuming here that all the other nodes with corresponding partition key ranges are down) and we can potentially lose our data due to coordinator's failure. But wait a minute.... as I understand it, if we used CL = ONE and for example we had only one(of three) available node for this partition key, we would have only one node with inserted data. Risk of loss is the same.

But I think we should assume equal situations - all nodes for particular token is gone. Then it's better to discard write operation then write with such a big risk of coordinator's loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CL=ANY should probably never be used on a production server. Writes will be unavailable until the hint is written to a node owning that partition because you can't read data when its in a hints log.

Using CL=ONE and RF=3 with two nodes down, you would have data stored in both a) the commit log and memtable on a node and b) the hints log. These are likely different nodes, but they could be the same 1/3 of the time.  So, yes, with CL=ONE and CL=ANY you risk complete loss of data with a single node failure.

Instead of ANY or ONE, use CL=QUORUM or CL=LOCAL_QUORUM.

Comment: Thank you, short and strait to the point of my question! I know how to get strong consistency....and available options for that. Formula for strong consistency is 'CL for read +  CL for write > RF'. I just was trying to figure out probabilities for ANY and ONE case and you help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the hints will just be stored for 3 hours by default and for longer times than that you have to run repairs. You can repair if you have at least one copy of this data on one node somewhere in the cluster (hints that are stored on coordinator don't count).

Consistency One guarantees that at least one node in the cluster has it in commit log no matter what. Any is in worst case stored in hints of coordinator (other nodes can't access it) and this is stored by default in a time frame of 3 hours. After 3 hours pass by with ANY you are loosing data if other two instances are down.

If you are worried about the risk, then use quorum and 2 nodes will have to guarantee to save the data. It's up to application developer / designer to decide. Quorum will usually have slightly bigger latencies on write than One. But You can always add more nodes etc. should the load dramatically increase.

Also have a look at this nice tool to see what impacts do various consistencies and replication factors have on applications:

https://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/

With RF 3, 3 nodes in the cluster will actually get the write. Consistency is just about how long you want to wait for response from them ... If you use One, you will wait until one node has it in commit log. But the coordinator will actually send the writes to all 3. If they don't respond coordinator will save the writes into hints.

Most of the time any in production is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it seems like a general information about consistency levels, time of storing hint. Not straight to my question. Thanks for the link anyway!